# Templated member function returning a templated class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write little openGL library.

Basically I have a `Uniform<T>` templated class and a `Shader` class that has a `GetUniform<T>(const char* name)` that should return an instance of the class `Uniform` with type `T`, also I don't want to do this with specialization because the code is same regardless of the type.

Uniform class code:

```
template<typename T>
class Uniform {
private:
    unsigned int _Location;
public:
    inline Uniform(unsigned int location) : _Location(location) {}
}
```

First `getUniform<T>` implementation:

```
template<typename T>
inline Uniform<T> getUniform(const char* name) const {
    unsigned int location = glGetUniformLocation(_ID, name);
    return Uniform<T>(location);
}
```

```
Fails with error:
error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
```

Second `getUniform<T>` implementation:

```
template<typename T>
inline auto getUniform(const char* name) const {
    unsigned int location = glGetUniformLocation(_ID, name);
    return Uniform<T>(location);
}
```

```
Fails with error:
error C3861: 'Uniform': identifier not found
```

### (Almost) Full Code:

### Shader.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Utils.h"
#include "Uniform.h"

class Shader {
private:
    unsigned int _ID;
    GLenum parseShaderDef(std::string line, bool first = false) {
        //STUFF
    }
    void compileShader(unsigned int id) {
        //STUFF
    }
public:
    inline Shader(const char* shaderFile) {
        //STUFF
    }
    inline ~Shader() {
        //TODO
    }

    template<typename T>
    inline Uniform<T> getUniform(const char* name) const {
        unsigned int location = glGetUniformLocation(_ID, name);
        return Uniform<T>(location);
    }

    inline void Bind() const {
        glUseProgram(_ID);
    }
    inline unsigned int getID() const {
        return _ID;
    }
    static inline void Unbind() {
        glUseProgram(0);
    }
};
```

### Uniform.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Utils.h"
#include "Shader.h"

template<typename T>
class Uniform {
private:
    unsigned int _Location;
public:
    inline Uniform(unsigned int location) : _Location(location) {}
    void operator=(T value) {};
};

template<>
void Uniform<bool>::operator=(bool value) {
    glUniform1i(_Location, value);
}
// All the other specializations
```

Also in the main file in include only uniform.h
Utils.h is a pch

Comment: The problem is in the order of declarations, but your question tells us nothing about it.

Comment: @Evg what you mean the function is inlined in the header file, and the uniform header is included

Comment: You include headers in such a way that `getUniform` is declared before `Uniform`. But the declaration of `Uniform` should come first. You might need some forward declarations. Without seeing headers with all `#include`s, it is impossible to tell which forward declarations and in which places you need.

Comment: You have a classical example of cross references: `Uniform.h` includes `Shader.h`, and `Shader.h` includes `Uniform.h`.

Comment: @Evg ok it worked i changed the include in the main file to shader.h, thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For us to help you, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not "almost" an example. Specifically, try placing your example code in a single c++ file.

Comment: @einpoklum by "almost" i mean i just removed the code that has no relevance, like the constructor of shader witch is 50 lines long, how can my be minimal if i can't remove parts that don't matter at all.

Comment: @samu698: The point is, we can't compile  the code you provided and get the error you mentioned, since we don't have "Utils.h". You said it's a precompiled header - ok, can you remove it and still get the same error? If not, again, we can't reproduce. And that's not to mention the infinite recursive `#include`ing you're doing.